# What is the point of <span> in HTML if there is <p>?

Tags: html

In the example pic I linked it shows the output of my HTML code on codeacademy. The output doesn't show any differences between `<p>` and `<span>`.

[image]

Comment: The point? Who knows? What's the context? Wrapping the text in a span allows you to select/style it independent of the paragraph.

Comment: Leaving my answer in this comment because someone already attempted an answer, but p tag adds a big margin (like a line-break) at the end of text. span tag on the other hand just puts the text in the middle of the line. Try "he<span>ll</span>o" and "he<p>ll</p>o" to notice the difference.

Answer (score 5):

- `<p>` is a **block-level** element that represents a paragraph, not a run of text.
- `<span>` is an **inline** elemnent that represents a run of text within a parent block of text. It has no semantic meaning unlike `<p>`, making is the inline equivalent of `<div>` (`<div>` represents a "division" in a document).

Because `<span>` has no default semantics it has no default style changes, so that's why the visual appearance is the same with, or without it, however because it exists it means you use it to target a specific run of text with style rules or use it in JavaScript and so on.